# sort of Include in an include - php

Tags: php

Here is what we have :-

We currently have a file system like this

$price = '3.00'; - this in turn is then included into a different file for use within the template system.

what we want to do may seem a bit long winded but it seems the easiest to us to get around.

what we are going to have is one file which will static price and will be updated via a .net application so all the .php contains is 3.00

then... we come back to the main file and this is where we are getting stuck

we have tried methods like this

```
<? 
$file = file_get_contents('/home/habbo/www/order/pricex2.php');
echo $file;
$price = '$file';
?>
```

we have tried to put an include within the = ' '; bit and that doesnt seem to work and im not too sure how we are meant to add it , i thought the $file might of worked but it just simple outputs the $file

is there much i am doing wrong

Comment: there are theses newfangled things called data bases, i highly recommend one.

Comment: not really worth it for just the 1 page

Comment: Why does that data file have a .php extension, if it doesn't contain any PHP code? Also elaborate on the expected and actual outcome, else the what-you've-tried part is irrelevant.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Erm, I think you need:

```
$price = $file;
```

or (slower):

```
$price = "$file";
```

Since PHP variables are not interpolated within single-quoted strings.

You can convert it into a floating point number like this:

```
$price = floatVal($file);

// or
$price = (float)$file;

// or (icky, but..)
$price = $file + 0.0;
```

Comment: Maybe even throw a `floatval()` in.

Comment: Why do you need to bother with floatval? PHP variables are loosely typed.

Comment: @migimaru - don't know if it is 'needed', I suspect it is not - why not throw in conversion just for the extra bit of knowledge. Yes, PHP is loosely typed, but pass a string to a function/method which does type-checking internally and kablam!